# Joint pdf on a unit disk with differnt distribution in two halfs

Tags: probability

We are given a joint distribution of $f(x,y)= 3a$ on the upper half of a unit disk ($0<y\le1$) and $f(x,y)=a$ in the lower half ($-1\le y<0$). I am having trouble setting up the double integral over the entire area to determine $a$. Intuitively I think I should weigh the upper half area $\frac{3}2$ times compared the lower half and set the sum of the two weighted areas to 1 but am stuck on setting it up mathematically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Area of half disc is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (radius=1).  Contributions to the distribution of the 2 halves are $3a\frac{\pi}{2}\ and\ a\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the ratio is 3:1.